# Material UI textfield 'disable' prop won't update more than once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, use-state

Trying to make a program where there are radio switches each equating to a different boolean value. Depending on the boolean value, it would either make the 'disable' prop on the textfield either true or false. My code allows for the button to be default selected as enabled editing and when I select disable it disables the textfield. However, if I click disable then try and click enable again it won't change the textfield from disable.

```
  const [radioEdit, setRadioEdit] = React.useState(false);

        <RadioGroup
          value={radioEdit}
          onChange={(e) => setRadioEdit(e.target.value)}
          aria-labelledby="demo-radio-buttons-group-label"
          name="radio-buttons-group"
          row
        >
          <FormControlLabel
            value={true}
            control={<Radio />}
            label="Disabled"
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            value={false}
            control={<Radio />}
            label="Enabled"
          />

            <p>{String(radioEdit)}</p>

            <TextField
              id="outlined-basic"
              variant="outlined"
              size="small"
              ////////RIGHT HERE////////
              value={data["companyname"]}
              disabled={radioEdit}
            />
```

[image]

If the default state of radioEdit isn't 'false', it is automatically disabled (set to true or null) and won't let me update it multiple times.

Comment: Let me be clear on your question. so you should be able to toggle between 'disabled' and 'enabled' on click. Am I correct?

Comment: and if you could provide with a reusable code would be useful

Comment: yes, if the editing radio button is on enabled then the Name textfield should be writeable. If the radio button is on disabled then the Name textfield is disabled. My issue is it won't update back n fourth between the 2. If I have it defaulted to enabled it allows editing but if I click disable it disables the textfield and won't re-enable it even after I like enable again

Comment: Hi so the issue is with 'onChange={(e) => setRadioEdit(e.target.value)}' change that to 'onChange={(e) => setRadioEdit(!radioEdit)}'. let me know if that works

Comment: That works, can you explain where I went wrong with my onChange?

Comment: @Zachphilipp `e.target.value` will always be a string (even though you are passing a boolean to the component), because radio input values are strings. The strings `"true"` and `"false"` are both [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) values so once your `onChange` executes, `radioEdit` becomes a truthy string.

Comment: @Zachphilipp Here's a sandbox demonstrating: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-voice-ok61bm?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I understand now that the type being passed effected my issue. I do not understand the '!' symbol in the setRadioEdit(!radioEdit) portion of code. What is the purpose of that

Comment: @Zachphilipp ! refers to NOT. Like '==' refers EQUALS TO. '!=' refers NOT EQUAL TO

Comment: @Zachphilipp and the issue is not just the type being passed. It's also what value is being passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with `onChange` you have defined with `RadioGroup`. Usually, we define
`onChange={(e) => setRadioEdit(e.target.value)}`
to set the value of text input onEventChangeHandler. But here it's for the Radio button. I was using typescript to find the answer for this and as soon as I copy-pasted your code it showed me the error at `setRadioEdit(e.target.value)` whereas the `setRadioEdit` should be boolean. The reason why TypeScript is super useful.
The answer is

```
onChange={() => setRadioEdit(!radioEdit)}
```

I'm toggling my state here `onChange`. So when we `setRadioEdit` as `true`, it's actually the `radioEdit` would be set as `true`. That's how the `useState` hook works. So by defining `setRadioEdit(!radioEdit)` we are toggling the state. If it's `true` it changes to `false` and vice versa.

Also you will have to close the `</RadioGroup>` component. Complete answer

```
const [radioEdit, setRadioEdit] = useState(false);  

return (
    <>
  
  <RadioGroup
    value={radioEdit}
    onChange={(e) => setRadioEdit(!radioEdit)}
    aria-labelledby="demo-radio-buttons-group-label"
    name="radio-buttons-group"
    row
  >
    <FormControlLabel value={true} control={<Radio />} label="Disabled" />
    <FormControlLabel value={false} control={<Radio />} label="Enabled" />
  </RadioGroup>

  <p>{String(radioEdit)}</p>

  <TextField
    id="outlined-basic"
    variant="outlined"
    size="small"
    disabled={radioEdit}
  />
</> 

 );
```

Comment: Make sure to mark it correct @Zach phillip ;)